# Error with "Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_LCOpenSDK_PlayWindow"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have added this "LCOpenSDKDynamic" custom framework for some video surveillance project into my swift project. I have tried all the ways I found in the web but finally got stuck into the following error.
Here is the framework 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8u5aw0t5oc4shj/LCOpenSDKDynamic.framework.zip?dl=0

I have added the needed header files into bridging header like

```
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_AudioTalk.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_PlayWindow.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_EventListener.h>
#import <LCOpenSDKDynamic/LCOpenSDK_TalkerListener.h>
```

Tried adding target into project.

If I do not call the Class from any of my project file build get successfull, but if initiate any class like

```
var m_play:LCOpenSDK_PlayWindow?

m_play = LCOpenSDK_PlayWindow.init(playWindow: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), index: 0)
```

Build got failed.

Here is error https://pasteboard.co/ImphzT1.png

Comment: Are you using a simulator or a real device to run the project?

Comment: I tried both, but every time i get the same error.

Comment: Hello i just tested it working for real device now, but for that I had to change the value from yes to no into Enable bitcode from build settings. what about the emulator?? I am still getting this error for emulator.

Comment: Then LCOpenSDKDynamic might not be the one including Architecture for Simulator. You need to test it in either Real device all the times or get the LCOpenSDKDynamic framework with Architecture for simulator.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will talk to them about it.